# How do I root my Samsung Galaxy Ace?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-ace

I want to root my Galaxy Ace but don't want to install Custom ROM or CWM!

Just only root so that, I can run some apps which requires root.

Comment: Try one click root or you can easily find root guide on xda forums..

Comment: It would help if we knew what Android version it is running, and also if you have managed to root it in the month that this question has been up?

Comment: @LiamW : I have the same phone, Its running android 2.3.6 Gingerbread with kernel version 2.6.38.6

Answer (score 2):

[Everything](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1034145) you need to know about rooting and installing custom ROM on your phone.

a. Rooting for 2.2.1:

```
Turn on your phone
Enable Debugging at Apliccations>Programming
Connect your phone into PC via cable
Launch Super One Click 2.3.3
Click "Root"
Wait until the program will root your phone
When the process is complete turn off SOC and unplug your phone
Reboot
Now you have root!
```

Db. Rooting for 2.3.x (NEW METHOD!):

```
Download file called universal_gb_root_v25.zip and copy it to your sdcard
Turn off your phone
Press POWER+HOME BUTTON
Select update from sdcard, select the file universal_gb_root_v25.zip
After the update completed - reboot
Now you have rooted S5830
```

OPTIONAL Unrooting for 2.3.x:

```
Download file called universal_gb_unroot_v9.zip and copy it to your sdcard
Turn off your phone
Press POWER+HOME BUTTON
Select update from sdcard, select the file universal_gb_unroot_v9.zip
After the update completed - reboot
Now you have unrooted S5830[/QUOTE]
```

ps: its best you read the first link.

Comment: Could you give some excerpt of the linked article? We don't favor "link-only" answers, as when the link dies those answers get useless.

Comment: Added. But it's best if OP reads the whole link. Threads on XDA are hardly ever moved and there permalink is more or less same :)

Comment: I don't argue against reading the original article (I rather agree). But it's this site's policy to not use link-only answers, and I agree with that as well :) Thank you!

Comment: No problem. added it and will add excerpts in future answers as well :)